# AJAX call in an Infowindow: Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Or at least I believe it's a scope issue, correct me if I'm wrong.

I have a for loop that generates markers on my map. Each infowindow loads different content using callbacks to an ajax function.

I've simplified this sample to outline the problem.

```
var xhr = "";
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
var polylineCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762, 17.917843),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(-0.829439, -91.112473),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(15.066156, -23.621399),
                          ]


function createHttpRequest() {
    try {   
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return xhr;
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            //assume IE6
            try {
            xhr = new activeXBbject("microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            return xhr;
            }
            catch (e)   {
                return alert("Unable to create an XMLHttpRequest object");
            }
        }
}



  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762,17.917843),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }



//I recreated the polylineCoordinates array (see above)
//to try and replicate and real array in the script

for (i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: polylineCoordinates[i],
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent("<div id=\"infowindow\">" + getStationInfo(infoWindowDiv) + "</div>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        }
    })(marker, i));

} //End adding markers loop


            function infoWindowDiv(stationInfo) {
                var add = document.createTextNode(stationInfo);
                document.getElementById("infowindow").appendChild(add);
            }


            function getStationInfo(callback) {
                //createHttpRequest() exists globally
                var xhr = createHttpRequest();
                var url = "stations.php" //edited out the original URL
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var stationInfo = "This is a Test";
                        return callback(stationInfo)
                    } //end readyState

                } //end readystatechange
                xhr.open("GET", url, true);
                xhr.send(null);
            } //end getStationInfo
```

*Small Edit: Moved functions outside of the loop*

**Edit 2:** There is nothing wrong with the ajax call, the url was edited for the sake of the sample code. Notice the final output shows "This is a test" in the infowindow which clearly states a successful callback was performed. Moreover, notice there is no responseText or responseXml. The variable being sent back has nothing to do with the url

The callback works fine but for some reason it's topped with the dreadful 'undefined' on top of it.
Console shows nothing.
Output:

```
undefined
This is a test
```

What am I doing wrong? How can it be undefined if it works?

Comment: You're defining your functions infoWindowDiv and getStationInfo inside of a loop, i.e. you're re-creating them `polylineCoordinates.length` number of times.  Move them outside of that loop.  This shouldn't be causing your problem, it's just bad practice

Comment: @duncan, Thanks for the input. Functions are now outside of the loop but functionality remains the same...

Comment: What is your `createHttpRequest` function doing?

Comment: Please provide enough code to replicate the problem (or a fiddle or a link to a page that does).  You can't return anything in the onreadystatchange function of getStationInfo.

Comment: It creates an XMLHttpRequest(). I'm pretty confident it's not the issue as it works fine on a different part of the script. I didn't add it so I could keep the sample code on topic. I'll add some more now.

Comment: @duncan I've added some more code to the sample to try and replicate what goes on the real script

Comment: ah, one thing that might be happening.  So you're creating a div with id=infowindow from inside your markers' event listener. And the content of that div is determined by a function which in turn ultimately tries to refer to the infowindow itself using `document.getElementById("infowindow")`.  In other words you might be trying to use getElementById before the infowindow has been created

Comment: Why are your `polylineCoordinates` items defined as strings? `"new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762, 17.917843)",
                           "new google.maps.LatLng(-0.829439, -91.112473)"`.

Comment: @duncan I removed all notion of getElementById to test this out, output remains the same. I played around with the content of the infowindow, whenever getStationInfo() or infoWindowDiv() are used, undefined is displayed in the infowindow along with their output. I just don't get it, they are in the same scope!

Comment: @user1477388 In reality, `polylineCoordinates` 's  contents get inserted inside a loop using `push`, it is a valid array. What you see above is something illustrated for this sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening:

1. you click on the infowindow
2. getStationInfo(infoWindowDiv) is called, fires off an AJAX request, but returns nothing useful ("undefined", there is no return statement)
3. The AJAX function will encounter an error (url "Unnecessary at this point" will not cause the onreadystatechange function to fire).  But you tell us that isn't a problem.
4. The script encounters the javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null` because the div with id infowindow hasn't been attached to the DOM.

Suggest adding an event listener on the infowindow to not attempt to access the div with id="infowindow" until it has been rendered (domready).

Working code:

```
    var xhr = "";
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = null;
    var marker, i;
    var polylineCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762, 17.917843),
                               new google.maps.LatLng(-0.829439, -91.112473),
                               new google.maps.LatLng(15.066156, -23.621399)
                              ]


      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762,17.917843),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

    for (i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: polylineCoordinates[i],
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent("<div id=\"infowindow\" style=\"height:50px;width:200px;\"></div>");
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow,"domready", function(){
                  getStationInfo(infoWindowDiv);
                });
        })(marker, i));

    } //End adding markers loop

    }
            function infoWindowDiv(stationInfo) {
                var add = document.createTextNode(stationInfo);
                document.getElementById("infowindow").appendChild(add);
            }


            function getStationInfo(callback) {
                var stationInfo = "This is a Test";
                callback(stationInfo)
            } //end getStationInfo

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The Ajax function works just fine, I just edited out the original url for the sake of the sample. Notice the final output shows "This is a test" in the infowindow which clearly states that a successful callback was performed. Moreover, notice there is no responseText or responseXml. The variable being sent back has nothing to do with the url. That is definitely not what's wrong with the script...

Comment: That is nice.  If you want us to do more than guess we either have to make up a URL that works or you need to provide one.  When I attempt to run your code I get fairly obvious javascript errors (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null <page name>:80`)

Comment: You might as well have google.com set as a url! No responseText is defined within the confines of xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200! url is not the source of the problem.

Comment: If you're trying to run the script, just set the url variable to anything valid and it'll go through. Notice we're not extracting any information from it.

Comment: Additional question: The second event listener works but in return I'm encountering an additional issue: The first time you click a marker everything work flawlessly, the second time you click it you get the same output twice, and it builds up that way. For example, if we're testing with an alert(), the first time you click the infowindow, you'll get one alert, second time, two alerts, third click, three alerts.. and so on. I'm having a hard time understanding this behavior, any thoughts? Hope I made the question clear enough.