# Javascript closures - passing infowindow id inside for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, closures

The infowindows are placed on the map using a loop. Their content is generated with an AJAX call. The AJAX's URL is determined by that same loop. If I call the AJAX function once the page has been rendered, then the loop is over and I can no longer use the counter `i`.

```
var xhr = "";
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

//Sample array
var polylineCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762, 17.917843),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(-0.829439, -91.112473),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(15.066156, -23.621399),
                          ]

var polylineNames = [one,
                     two,
                     three,
                          ]


function createHttpRequest() {
    try {   
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return xhr;
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            //assume IE6
            try {
            xhr = new activeXBbject("microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            return xhr;
            }
            catch (e)   {
                return alert("Unable to create an XMLHttpRequest object");
            }
        }
}



  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762,17.917843),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }




    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: polylineCoordinates[i],
        map: map
      });
      markers.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent("<div id=\""polylineNames[i]"\" style=\"height:50px;width:200px;\">"+polylineNames[i]+"</div>");

      infowindow.open(map, marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,"domready", function(){
      getStationInfo(infoWindowDiv);
            });
    }
  })(marker, i));

}//End polylineCoordinates loop (adding markers loop)


    function infoWindowDiv(doc){
       //doc can be parsed here and displayed in the infowindow
          }

   function getStationInfo(callback) {
    var xhr = createHttpRequest();
    //***This will no longer work as the loop is over. How do I get the infowindow div id?
    var url = "Station_"+polylineNames[i]+".php";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var doc = xhr.responseXML;
                return callback(doc)
        }//end readyState

    }//end readystatechange
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);
    xhr.send(null);
}//end getStationInfo
```

As you can see, because the AJAX function is called once the loop is over, the `i` variable is no longer relevant.

I can't just put the AJAX function inside the setContent because that outputs `undefined`.

What I had in mind as a solution was passing the infowindow id to the AJAX function `getStationInfo` and setting the wanted url that way, but I couldn't wrap my head around how to do that. Perhaps using `this` somehow?

**The ultimate goal** here is to retrieve the relevant file from the server. Then I can parse and append it to the infowindow.

And if there's another method of how to go about this, I'd sure like to know about it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: your question seems unclear and incomplete. You speak of some loop but there is none. You use `i` counter but there is no use for it in the code you post. What is the point? Post complete code. This is confusing.

Comment: Please look under **Code for visualization** for the entire script including the said loop and the `i` counter. Specifically under the initialize() function.

Comment: OK, now I see. Your question was too complicated and confusing. I cleaned it up so that only the confusing and irrelevant pieces of code cut out of context are not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Code:**

```
var xhr = "";
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

//Sample array
var polylineCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762, 17.917843),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(-0.829439, -91.112473),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(15.066156, -23.621399),
                          ]

var polylineNames = [one,
                     two,
                     three,
                          ]


function createHttpRequest() {
    try {   
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return xhr;
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            //assume IE6
            try {
            xhr = new activeXBbject("microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            return xhr;
            }
            catch (e)   {
                return alert("Unable to create an XMLHttpRequest object");
            }
        }
}



  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(78.782762,17.917843),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }




    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: polylineCoordinates[i],
        map: map
      });
      markers.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent("<div id=\""polylineNames[i]"\" style=\"height:50px;width:200px;\">"+polylineNames[i]+"</div>");

      infowindow.open(map, marker);

      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow,"domready", function(){
      getStationInfo(polyNames[i]);
            });
    }
  })(marker, i));

}//End polylineCoordinates loop (adding markers loop)



   function getStationInfo(id) {
    var xhr = createHttpRequest();
    var url = "Station_"+id+".php";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var doc = xhr.responseXML;
         /*
         ***Begin parsing here or return doc to another function
         */ 
        }//end readyState

    }//end readystatechange
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);
    xhr.send(null);
}//end getStationInfo
```

**What changed?**

1. id variable `polyNames[i]` is sent to the AJAX function `getStationInfo` from within the loop.
2. `infoWindowDiv` function made redundant.
3. AddListerner changed to AddListenerOnce to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use javascript closures but you do it the wrong way - in the setting of the google event handler:

```
for (i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            ....
        }
    })(marker, i));
    # ... do something here
}
function getStationInfo(callback) { 
    # trying to use i here
}
```

The correct way is to use the closure right inside the for loop, so that it wraps the whole loop, and place the AJAX handler *inside* the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length; i++)
(function(marker, i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            ....
    });

    function getStationInfo(callback) { 
        # you can use i here even if it's an ajax callback
    }
    # you can use marker and i anywhere inside here even if it's in an ajax 
    # callback - it will be set correctly as it was during the loop run
})(marker, i));
```

This way you can use `marker` and `i` anywhere inside the loop even if it's in an ajax 
callback - **thanks to closures it will be set correctly as it was during the loop run**.

Comment: Having the closures inside the loop was how my script was structured initially. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801104/ajax-call-in-an-infowindow-scope-issue). Having the closures inside actually provided the correct output but topped by an `undefined` error. This is because the `getStationInfo` renders the infowindow before it is "domready". The solution was moving them outside of the loop with a new event handler inside, which then provided me with a new issue.

Comment: 1) The closures are inside the loop in all of your examples, there's no change in this. The difference is *where* the closure is within the loop. 2) The question you linked doesn't try what I propose here. Your error must have had a different cause. Try to modify the code to what I propose.

Comment: Rephrasing my problem: I can put my closure in or out of the loop(I tried what you suggested), but as long as I use the `i` counter to fetch the url, then by all means the DOM is not yet rendered which in return gives me an `undefined` or an `Uncaught TypeError` when I set the content of the infowindow. If I use an event listener triggered by `domready`, then the DOM is rendered, I can access the infowindow with no errors BUT `i` is now useless as the loop has finished. I hope this explains it a little further, I'll try to find another example to visualize my problem some more.

Comment: *"I tried what you suggested"*. OK, post full working example of your code with my change included into jsfiddle.net. Then we can discuss what problems you encountered there.

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ba6VA/2/). It works in my browser. I don't know why it won't accept the arrays. Anyway, it appends but with an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null. `. With this version, the AJAX function `getStationInfo` will work the same inside or outside the loop.

Comment: your code doesn't run. It doesn't even display the map - there is some javascript error. And, this code doesn't do what I proposed. I told you to put the closure just after the for loop.